# text with multiple colors in legend with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Instead of many entries within a legend I'd like to add one text line which describes multiple lines. I'm looking to an automatic way to do this, instead of fiddling around with the coordinates of the according text object.

Right now I'm using a function which takes the coordinates at which the text should start, a list of strings and a list of colors. Then the function assembles the strings using the colors. Is there a way to get the coordinates of an empty legend string (I just plot nothing with an empty label for that)?

I tried something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,6.19, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

ax = plt.gca()

p1 = ax.plot(x,y, label="test")

# list of text objects
text = [mpl.text.Text(0,0,'$a=$'), mpl.text.Text(0,0,'$2$')]

# HPacker of text objects
# right way to get them into the legend?
hp = mpl.offsetbox.HPacker(children=text)

lgd = plt.legend([p1,??], ['legend1',??])
plt.show()
```

Couldn't find out how to add the HPacker to the legend.
Is the HPacker the right way to assemble (text-)objects horizontally for the usage as an item within a legend?